# How to make the selenium web driver click on a button which is inside react spotlight (React Joyride)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, selenium, capybara

I've added a controlled tour in my app using ReactJoyride. At a particular step, the tour will progress only when the 'Ongoing' tab/button is clicked (see image).

[image]

This 'Ongoing' button is inside the spotlight.

I've tested this manually and it works perfectly. However, while testing this using Selenium, I can't seem to find a way to click on this button.

I'm getting the following error :

[image]

It says that react-joyride__overlay will receive the clicks. But react-joyride__spotlight is a child element of react-joyride__overlay and i've enabled spotlightClicks.

The current code that i'm using is this : (test.rb)
[image]

- the commented lines of code are the other ways that i've tested. All of them failed.

If you can point me in the correct direction, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: You are supposed to include the selenium tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, your desired element is overlay-ed by other element, so this other element is hiding your element. All you have to do is, you have check whether this overlay is permanent or temporary. If it's temporary, you have to write the code to wait until the other element gets disappeared, If it's permanent, then you have to issue the click on top of the other element so that your desired element would receive the click.

Let me assume your overlay is permanent so try this code

```
find(xpath: "//div[@class='react-joyride__overlay']").click
```

Comment: thanks for answering. However, your solutions is not working. 
FIrst of, it was giving me a syntax error.  I suppose you meant 
`find(:xpath, "//div[@class='react-joyride__overlay']").click`? 
I think it is clicking the overlay, but the button inside that isn't being clicked. 
Also, the next step will only be rendered once the button's onClick method is called. Do you have any other suggestions?